# Custom ExUnit assertions and pattern matching

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I'm writing a flexible, adapter-based error tracking library and provide a set of custom test assertion functions to make integration tests easier to work with.

I have something like

```
  # /lib/test_helpers.ex 

  ...

  @doc """
  Asserts specific exception and metadata was captured

  ## Example

      exception = %ArgumentError{message: "test"}
      exception |> MyApp.ErrorTracker.capture_exception(%{some_argument: 123})
      assert_exception_captured %ArgumentError{message: "test"}, %{some_argument: 123}
  """
  def assert_exception_captured(exception, extra) do
    assert_receive {:exception_captured, ^exception, ^extra}, 100
  end
```

Which will pass the exact exception to the `assert_exception_captured`, but it does not work when trying to pattern match on for example the struct of the exception.

I'd like to be able to do this

```
...
assert_exception_captured _any_exception, %{some_argument: _}
```

How can I make this work with pattern matching?

Much appreciated

Comment: Your code looks good to me. What does `MyApp.ErrorTracker.capture_exception` do?

Comment: Currently it just echos back the arguments using message passing 

`send self(), {:exception_captured, exception, extra}`

Comment: That works for me. Can you add a complete test case which fails for you?

Comment: @Dogbert I added an example of what'd I'd like to be able to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use macros if you want to be able to pass in a pattern. This is how you can implement it with a macro:

```
defmacro assert_exception_captured(exception, extra) do
  quote do
    assert_receive {:exception_captured, ^unquote(exception), unquote(extra)}, 100
  end
end
```

Test:

```
test "greets the world" do
  exception = %ArgumentError{message: "test"}
  send self(), {:exception_captured, exception, %{some_argument: 123}}
  assert_exception_captured exception, %{some_argument: _}
end
```

Output:

```
$ mix test
.

Finished in 0.02 seconds
1 test, 0 failures
```

Comment: Hmm, for me this results in the error `unbound variable _`

Comment: Ah nvm, I was using `bind_quoted: [...]`, but if I use `unquote` instead it works. I thought it did the same thing